# Как задать только для одного "UL LI A"?

Tags: drupal, html, css

Как задать только для одного "UL LI A", а то когда задаю, распространяется и на другие подгруппы.

**Обновление**

Это не то. Мне только надо, чтобы не распространялась на подгруппы, типа чтобы только на дочернюю, например, `<span> </span>` типа того. Что прописать чтобы только на меню, а на подгруппы не подействовала.
Я не могу изменить `html`, через css делаю, как это сделать чтобы только на первую `ul li` a действовала, на саму меню а не на подгруппу? Drupal 7 тема zen

Вот css

```
#superfish-1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Georgia;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.01s;
}
#superfish-1 li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
#superfish-1 li ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 55px;
}
#superfish-1 li ul li {
    float: none;
    height:55px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #7F7F7F;
}

#superfish-1 li a {
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#superfish-1 li:hover ul, #superfish-1 li.jshover ul {
    display: block;
}
#superfish-1 li:hover, #superfish-1 li.jshover {
    background: #424242;
}

#superfish-1 li a:hover{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.01s;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #444;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Вы не [ЭТО](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child) искали? Или вам надо, например, где-нить в середине чтобы он располагался?

Comment: Вроде это, как это в css коде прописать? чтобы на подгруппы не распространялась

Comment: Так вы внимательно статью почитайте - там примеры есть.

Comment: @Саша202020, Оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="menu">

  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

файл

> style.css

в нем

```
.menu{
   background:#cc0000;
}
```

либо

```
<ul >

  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a class="menu" href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

файл

> style.css

в нем

```
.menu{
   background:#cc0000;
}
```

может Вам это поможет

Answer (score 0):

[[@Саша202020](/users/26100/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0202020)](/users/26100/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0202020), cудя по описанию, вам нужен прямо так и называемый [дочерний селектор](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/child) UL>LI A. прочитайте про селекторы в CSS, справа колонка на сайте и поищите нужные варианты.

Answer (score 0):

используйте ">" он явно указывает на то что стиль применяется для заданной вложенности, например:

```
#superfish-1 > ul > li {
color: #000;
}
```

код выше не будет применен к #superfish-1 ul li ul li